# $ \int^{\infty}_0 |\frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt x}|^p ~ \mathrm dx < \infty \implies p=?$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

If $ f(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt x} $ how to find all $ p > 0 $ such that
$$ \int^{\infty}_0 |f(x)|^p dx < \infty $$
The integral is with respect to lebesgue measure. Any solution or hints would be helpful. The answer is the integral converges iff $ p\in (\frac{2}{3}, 2) $.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At $+\infty$, you have
$$
|f(x)|^p\sim \frac{1}{x^{3p/2}}
$$
which converges if and only if $3p/2>1$.

At $0$, 
$$
|f(x)|^p\sim\frac{1}{x^{p/2}}
$$
which converges if and only if $p/2<1$.

So your integral converges if and only if
$$
\frac{2}{3}<p<2.
$$

Comment: Thanks. I think the following estimates solve the problem.

Comment: Yes. All you need to know is that $\int_0^11/x^\alpha dx$ converges if and only if $\alpha<1$, and $\int_1^{+\infty}1/x^\beta dx$ converges if and only if $\beta>1$. For a proof, simply compute the integrals.

Comment: Neat solution! I've worked it out for myself and it's a cool problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Since
$$\int_0^{\infty} f(x)^p dx =\int_0^1 f(x)^p dx+\int_1^{\infty} f(x)^p dx$$

So if $0<p<1$, we can only consider the integral $\int_1^{\infty} f(x)^p dx$, and
$$\int_1^{\infty} f(x)^p dx < \int_1^\infty \left(\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}\right)^p dx$$

And
$$\int_1^\infty f(x)^p dx > \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x)^{3p/2}} dx .$$

Comment: The integral from $0$ to $1$ is also not always bounded for all $p$, I have the answer as if $ p \in (\frac{2}{3},2) $ only then integral is finite, but all of it is not exactly clear from these estimates. A little elaboration would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using the change of variables $ z=\frac{1}{1+x} $ and the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

$$ \beta(x,y) = \int_{0}^{1}t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt,\quad Re(x),\,Re(y)>0, $$

we have

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{(1+x)^p x^{\frac{p}{2}}} dx = \int _{0}^{1}\! \left( 1-z \right) ^{-\frac{p}{2}}{z}^{\frac{3p}{2}-2}{dz}.$$

Comparing with the existence conditions for the beta function implies that

$$ 1-\frac{p}{2}>0,\quad\frac{3p}{2}-1 > 0. $$

Solving the two inequalities gives the desired result.

Comment: So you find $p<0$ and $4/3<p$. There is a problem.

Comment: @Juilien: I made a small correction. The inequalities are $1-\frac{p}{2}>0$ and $ \frac{3p}{2}-1>0 $. I already mentioned comparing with the existence conditions for the beta function.